# What should I cover the ground in my garden with?

Tags: vegetables

I have not covered my garden all winter, did not know I was suppose to until now. I am ready to plant my garden but want to know best way to prepare the soil and should I cover garden with bark? I am beginning a compost pile now

Comment: What's your climate like (or where is it)? What are you wanting to grow? What kind of soil is it (sandy, clay, loam, clay loam, silt, caliche, etc.)? Have you had a soil test (fertility and pH)? Where did you hear you were supposed to cover your garden? What's the reason for it? Is it necessary in your area or is it something that just improves matters in a certain way somehow?

Comment: I ‘m also surprised about the “you are supposed to cover” statement. Please [edit] your post with details, thanks! And: welcome to Gardening SE! The [tour] and the [help] will tell you more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

Margie, I think I know where your going with this.In the fall,I generally leave the leaves in the flower beds.I think it helps protect the plants in case of a really hard winter. In the spring I clean them out real good then mulch. Depending on what you are planting, check with a local garden center and they can give you some ideas. You may want to amend the soil,(put nutrients back),your compost may take a while so,get some over the counter fertilizer if needed. Happy Spring!